# Add line break to xCharts xaxis

Tags: svg, javascript

I want to add a line break in the xaxis of [xCharts](http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts).
I have been trying to add the line break with `<tspan>` unsuccessfully.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
// Set initial data
var data = {
  "xScale": "time",
  "yScale": "linear",
  "type": "line",
  "main": [
    {
      "className": ".foo",
      "data": [
        {
          "x":"2013-08-06 14:30:00",
          "y":12
        },
        {
          "x":"2013-08-06 14:30:01",
          "y":8
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// Set options
var opts = {
  "dataFormatX": function(x) {
    return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').parse(x);
  },
  "tickFormatX": function(x) {

    /** This is where I'm adding the <tspan> **/
    return '<tspan>' + d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(x) + '</tspan>'
      + '<tspan x="0" dy="1em">' + d3.time.format('%H:%M:%S')(x) + '</tspan>';
  }
}

// Plot the graph
var recentChart = new xChart('line', data, '#recent-Chart', opts);
```

It should plot with YYYY-MM-DD then HH:MM:SS on the line below. But the generated output is as below:

```
<text y="3" x="0" dy=".71em" text-anchor="middle">&lt;tspan&gt;2013-08-06&lt;/tspan&gt;&lt;tspan x="0" dy="1em"&gt;14:30:00&lt;/tspan&gt;</text>
```

Escaping with `"\<tspan\>"` produces the same result.

How do I insert a line break?